# Pop! multiple items from Julia vector

Tags: julia

In the same way as `push!(collection, items...) -> collection` allows to add multiple items in one operation I want to `pop!` `n` items at once.
I am looking for this behavior

```
function popMany!(vector, n)
    result = vector[1:n]
    deleteat!(vector, 1:n)
    return result
end
```

I found the related [issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1854), but in contrast to the `push!` variations, `pop!(collection, n)` was never implemented.

Also `popat!.(1:9,1:3)` throws `DimensionMismatch`. `popfirst!` does not support additional arguments.

Is there already a function to pop multiple / many / a range of / indexed items?

Comment: The `popat!` version works fine if you write it as `popat!.(Ref(collect(1:9)), 3:-1:1)`, btw. Note that the range needs to be backwards so you get the expected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there already a function to pop multiple / many / a range of / indexed items?

`splice!`?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of a built-in function that does this automatically, but you can write a short one-liner using a comprehension:

```
julia> pop_many!(x, n) = [pop!(x) for _ in 1:n]
pop_many! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> x = rand(5)
5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.14855795213861422
 0.18593252832228968
 0.3353192149050159
 0.4537045868321117
 0.3912440300789175

julia> pop_many!(x, 3)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.3912440300789175
 0.4537045868321117
 0.3353192149050159

julia> x
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.14855795213861422
 0.18593252832228968
```